# Use Docker on a systemd disabled VM

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, docker, virtual-machine, sysvinit

I am provided by a VM running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS which has systemd disabled.

I have root access on it.

I am trying to run docker on it which is installed but I get error Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`. Is the docker daemon running?

I cannot run `systemctl` as I get error *System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.*

I ran the command `sudo service --status-all` and amongst the listed services Docker's service was not found.

The OS is using `sys-v` as `init`.

Is there a way I can user docker here?

PS: I asked the same question on [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360582/use-docker-on-a-systemd-disabled-vm?noredirect=1#comment2332159_1360582) and a guy in comments told me to ask here.

Edit:
As suggested in comments I tried to start docker daemon manually by using `dockerd` but it gave error

`` failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root) ``.

I am root, my terminal prompt is `root@05a4a97d8391:~#`  still I am executing `dockerd` using sudo and I did do `sudo -i` and `sudo su -` and my prompt remains same.

Comment: Try "apt update; apt install systemd".

Comment: Well, **is** the docker daemon running or not? If it is, check what socket it is listening on. If not, find out why. How did you start it?

Comment: Use `ps` to see if the docker demon is running. If not, start it manually. Once this works you can automate it via sys-v, if needed (just drop a shell script in the right `/etc/rc.X` directory).

Comment: @berndbausch docker daemon is not running.

Comment: @dirkt How do I start it manually? It's not running

Comment: Googling "docker start demon" finds https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/

Comment: @dirkt I did try and it failed, please read the edit in the question.

Comment: That most probably means OP is already in a container. See this Q/A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589995/docker-error-permission-denied-hello-world

Comment: @WilfredAlmeida please install the `virt-what` package, run `virt-what` and give the result.